# How to find IPs of Eureka registered service on the clients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have the following services:

- EurekaServer - hosts the eureka discovery server
- Client-service - registers to EurekaServer
- Finder-service - registers to EurekaServer

Is there a way to get Client-service's ip so I can make requests to it from the Finder-service.

I know there is a way to find InstanceInfo from EurekaServer and I was thinking of making a controller in eureka server where you pass service id and get service's instance ip. This way Finder-service would only need to know service id and eureka ip which it knows because it is registered there.

Is there another solution which is cleaner than this?

Comment: It answers your question... You don't need to write anything yourself as that would beat the point of service discovery.

Comment: How to get a service's instance info from a client then? If the question is answered as you say.

Comment: You don't need service-instance... Service discovery (aka resolving the IP) is transparant. You do something like `restTemplate.postForEntity("http://client-service/whatever")` and that is all you need to do/know. The resolution is done for you.

Comment: Can you formulate this as an answer or give me some links I can follow because it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You need `@EnableEurekaClient` or `@EnableDiscoveryClient` (AFAIK) and create a `RestTEmplate` `@Bean` method which itself is annotated with `@LoadBalanced`. This will install an interceptor which does the translation of service-name to ip/name to invoke.

Comment: Yes thank you , LoadBalanced was what i was missing, can you post it as an answer so I can accept and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use client discovery you first need to enable by adding either `@EnableEurekaClient` or `@EnableDiscoveryClient` to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class (or your specialized `@Configuration`).

Next to make use of the resolution of the actual service instance to use you need to create a `RestTemplate` which is load-balanced. This will add an interceptor which translates the service name into the ip-address / DNS name to send the request to (if multiple instances are found it will distribute the load between those instances).

To create a load balanced `RestTemplate` add the `@LoadBalanced` annotation to the configured `RestTemplate`.

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder rtb) {
    return rtb.build();
}
```

Now when doing a request through the `RestTemplate` it will resolve the service name `client-service` to the actual service instance to use. Without you having to do anything.